# Knockout binding iteration

Tags: knockout.js, knockout-3.0, knockout-binding-handlers

I am having a scenario where based on the Observable flag I need to iterate ABC and XYZ

Current Code

```
<div  data-bind="visible: isEnabled">
           <ul data-bind="foreach: relatedObservalableArray">
               <li>
               <!-- Hundred lines of code>
               </li>
            </ul>
</div>


<div data-bind="visible: !isEnabled">
        <ul data-bind="foreach: unRelatedObservalableArray">
               <li>
                <!-- Same Hundred lines of code>
               </li>
            </ul>
   </div>
```

I am feeling code duplicate.

Is any way I can group the two html functions to a single one?

I want to change only in HTML part due to some other ...

I am new to Knockout. Can someone help me?

Comment: If your code works but you want to improve it, your question certainly belongs to http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure you can use the knockout `template` binding for this.
Read it more [here](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/template-binding.html).

So for the changes it would be something like below but you can do variations basing on what you read from the link I gave.

```
<script type="text/html" id="template-name">
   Hundred lines of code...
</script>

<div  data-bind="visible: isEnabled">
  <ul data-bind="foreach: relatedObservalableArray">
    <li data-bind="template: 'template-name'">
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>


<div data-bind="visible: !isEnabled">
  <ul data-bind="foreach: unRelatedObservalableArray">
     <li data-bind="template: 'template-name'">
     </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```